# Dragging stops in the middle oncanvas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to drag mouse on the image (which is on the canvas) using the mouse events, it stops in the middle and doesnt parse the whole image. It is breaking in middle.
I am trying to make a rectangle using dragging mouse clicks on the image but it stops me to draw one big rectangle.

Can the reason be offset problem or memory leak.

Comment: Can you please provide us some code? http://jsfiddle.net/